# Getting stream.map to return List Spring boot?

Tags: spring-boot, kotlin

Trying to convert Author to Author Dto to return to List but it seems the only way it works is if I put Any or put it as a MutableList. Is there any way to fix this. Im using CrudRepository for my Author Repo

```
    fun entityToDto(author: Author): AuthorDto? {
        return AuthorDto(
                id = author.id,
                firstName = author.firstName,
                lastName = author.lastName,
                age = author.age,
                publisherName = author.publisher.name
        )

    }

    @GetMapping("/author")
    fun getAllAuthors(): Any {
       val authorList : List<Author> = authorRepo.findAll().toList()
        return authorList.stream().map { x -> entityToDto(x) }.collect(Collectors.toList())
    }
```

Comment: could you not just use `.toList()` after the map?

Comment: Oh i thought it would seem redundant since Collectors already has toList but it works now thanks

Comment: I'm just learning Kotlin, so I like to understand questions like these when they come up.  In this case, you wanted the return value of `getAllAuthors` to be a `List<>`, right?  That's the problem?  I don't understand why the code you show above won't work if you change `Any` to what you want. So the function def you want is`fun getAllAuthors(): List<AuthorDto?> {`, right?.  This works fine for me.  Did I get the point of the question wrong?